# If you have noun(s) as your subject, is your verb meant to be singular or plural?

Tags: grammar

I'm talking about the situation where you put (s) or /s in because the number/quantity of something is unknown.

For example, "Your complaint(s) is/are welcome" - is it "is" or "are"?

Comment: Plural subjects such as _complaints_ require the plural verb. Can you tell us what you have learned about the terms _singular_ and _plural_ in English?

Comment: @P. E. Dant I'm confused. Are you sure you understood my question? I'm referring to the case when people put an (s) in brackets after a noun because the number of the noun is unknown. (I'm a native speaker.)

Comment: I'd use the plural, but I don't have a source for this, so I'd rather not post that as an answer.

@P.E.Dant Unrelatedly, you seem to have a system going on with working people through answers. I'm hoping to start answering a lot of questions here, but I'd rather not undermine what you're trying to do. Should I do anything to solve that? I ask here because I don't know how to PM a user.

Comment: Heh! _You're_ confused? Seems more likely that _I_ am, or was. It's an intriguing question. I'll be surprised if there is any consensus on this. I would be inclined to write something quite like what you wrote in your question. Once you've taken the fatal step of putting that S in parentheses, the die is cast, and all morphological and syntactic bets are off.

Comment: @Lijero If by _system_ you mean my own flailing attempts at pseudo-Socratic pedagogy, the term is wildly flattering and implies a degree of organization of which I am incapable. I am but a harmless drudge. If on the other hand, as is more likely, you mean the ELL system, you can always open a question in Meta. I'm not sure what you mean by _undermine_ here. In any case, you should always answer any question to which you can provide useful answer. Votes will decide its value in Stackexchange reputational loot, and the questioner will let you know if it's useful.

Comment: OP: this question /might/ make more sense on English SE, not ELL SE, but I haven't been around long enough to say for sure.

@P.E.Dant Your "flailing attempts at pseudo-Socratic pedagogy" is exactly what I meant. I just don't want to interrupt the learning process by just giving the answer if you're trying to teach in a better way.

Comment: @Lijero My advice to you is not to worry about any undermining, to keep the interest of the questioner at the fore, and to go ahead and answer any question you see fit, just as you see fit, without a thought to any other contributor's methods. There are some stunning intellects here (and then there is mine, which is more often stunned) and after a while, you'll know when to get out of the way.

Comment: (+1) Good question, I had this problem myself. That's a real challenge when writing a technical or formal piece of writing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys. @Lijero I now think this question belongs on ELU too but I don't fancy being crucified for cross posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a good question indeed. I'm not a native speaker but I'll try to explain the way I understand it in English *(as a matter of fact it's almost done the same way in Russian)*:

If the noun tends to be plural in most cases, we use "**are**": -

- All Loughborough authors submitting **work(s) are** required to agree to the terms and conditions of the Institutional Repository Licence.
- What **weapon(s) are** you planning on using?

If the noun tends to be singular most of the time, we use "**is**":

- Any **rule(s)** that **is** not provided by the government **is** automatically subject to legislative review.
- While the **specimen(s) is** in transport, it may be classified as Exempt Human Specimens, Biological Substance (Category B), or Infectious Substance (Category A).
- To complete the diagnostic testing cycle for cancer, the genetic profile from the putative malignant **specimen(s) is** compared with the genetic profile derived from the patient’s DNA reference sample taken via cheek swab at the time of the biopsy procedure.

Most often people include both verbs:

- Which **statement(s) is/are** true about sexual reproduction?
- Which **sentence(s) is(are)** correct?

For a more common way it is better to avoid the optional plural form and use the plural form instead or rewrite the sentence in a different way:

- Your **ideas are** submitted for consideration. - Any amount of ideas. (In comparison to "Your idea(s) is(are) submitted for consideration.")